# Pickup rails changes on save NOT next request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whenever I make a code change, the rails server doesn't pick it up right away. Then the next request that comes in is delayed for about 20 seconds, even if the code was changed over a few minutes ago.

Is there any way around this?

I got no configuration for file watching.

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.11'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# We're not requiring them here because we do it in application.rb. We need
# mongoid to be loaded before ransack in order for ransack to load the mongoid
# adapter.
gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.4.0', require: false
gem 'ransack', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.9', require: false

# Was extracted from mongoid in mongoid 5.x
gem 'mongoid_rails_migrations'
gem 'kaminari-mongoid', '~> 1.0'

# address to lng/lat
gem 'geokit-rails'
# ip to geo. can replace the above one day.
gem 'geocoder'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# JSON baking
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.8.0'

gem 'money-rails', '~>1', github: 'nim901/money-rails'
gem 'angularjs-rails'
gem 'require_all', '~> 1.5'
# Display maps in views
gem 'gmaps4rails', '~> 2.1.2'
gem 'underscore-rails'

gem 'thin', '~> 1.8.1'

gem 'faraday', '~> 0.9'

gem 'websocket-rails', github: 'moaa/websocket-rails', branch: 'sync_fixes'
# Websocket rails requires this version of faye, otherwise we get connectivity
# issues.
gem 'faye-websocket', '0.10.0'

gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.5', '>= 2.5.3'

gem 'devise', '~> 4.4.3'
gem 'devise-security'

gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre5'
gem 'activeadmin-mongoid', github: 'nim901/activeadmin-mongoid', branch: 'nb/mongoid-5'

gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.9'

# maintenance of environment variables in application.yml
gem 'figaro'

# acts as state machine gem
gem 'aasm', '~> 4.11', '>= 4.11.1'

# Storing files on s3
gem 'paperclip', '~> 6.1'
gem 'mongoid-paperclip', '~> 0.0.11'

gem 'aws-sdk-lambda', '~> 1.31'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1.52'
gem 'aws-sdk-sns', '~> 1.20'
gem 'aws-sdk-ssm', '~> 1.58'
gem 'aws-sdk-rails', '~> 2.1'

gem 'rgeo', '~> 0.5.3'
gem 'ffi-geos'

gem 'mongoid-geospatial'

gem 'mechanize', require: false

gem 'carmen'
gem 'bcrypt'

gem 'koala' # FB

gem 'barby'
gem 'rqrcode'

gem 'active_admin_theme'

gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'authy'

gem 'nearest_time_zone' # convert ll to timezone
gem 'timezone' # To get local time
gem 'time_difference', '~> 0.5.0'

gem 'http'

# Validate Colors
gem 'chroma'

# User agent and stuff
gem 'browser'

gem 'activejob', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.7.1'
gem 'delayed_job_mongoid', '~> 2.3'

# POS Integrations
gem 'lightspeed_pos', github: 'yosi-dediashvili/lightspeed_pos'
gem 'shopify_api'
gem 'square', github: 'namedpipe/square'
gem 'magento_client'

# OmniAuth strategies
gem 'omniauth-lightspeed', '~> 1.0'
gem 'omniauth-clover'
gem 'omniauth-shopify-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-square', github: 'backupparachute/omniauth-square'
gem 'apple_id'

gem 'newrelic_rpm'

gem 'rest-client', '~> 2.0'

gem 'premailer-rails'

gem 'fast-stemmer'

gem 'activeadmin_addons', '~> 0.12.0'

gem 'gtin', git: 'https://github.com/yosi-dediashvili/gtin.git'

gem 'webmock'
gem "font-awesome-rails"

# For activeadmin charts
gem "chartkick"

# The long watied shipping!! developed by Shopify :~
gem "active_shipping", '2.1.1'
gem 'measured', '~> 2.4.0'

gem "gibbon", '~> 3.0'

gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'

# Used to convert BoxCheck's PDF label to PNG.
gem 'pdf-reader'

# Feature flipping.
gem 'flipper'
gem 'flipper-mongo'
gem 'flipper-ui'

# Wrapper for all the payment gateways.
gem 'activemerchant'

# payment processing for settlement of transactions upon merchant confirmation.
gem 'braintree', '~> 2.78'
gem 'stripe', '~> 5.34'

# Email templating
gem 'liquid', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.6'

gem "timerange"

# Parse natural language of date & time inputs.
gem 'chronic'

gem "wysiwyg-rails"
gem 'sendgrid-ruby'

gem 'redis-activesupport', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.7'
# Version 4 of redis causes websocket-rails to crash.
gem 'redis', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.5'

gem 'parallel', '~> 1.12.0'

gem 'mimemagic', '0.3.7'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.11.2'

# Easier console experience.
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'pry-byebug'
gem 'pry-stack_explorer'

gem 'google_maps_service'
gem 'googleauth', "~> 0.16.0", github: 'gabiberin/google-auth-library-ruby'
gem 'signet', "~> 0.14", github: 'gabiberin/signet'
gem 'google-ads-googleads', "~> 10.0.0"

gem 'rails_semantic_logger'

group :development do
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring', '~> 1.7', '>= 1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem "better_errors", github: 'charliesome/better_errors'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'derailed_benchmarks'
  gem 'bumbler'
  gem 'rails_semantic_logger'
end

group :test do
  gem 'dredd_hooks'
  gem 'seed_dump'
  gem 'fake_braintree', github: 'yosi-dediashvili/fake_braintree'
  # Used by fake_braintree, but setting this so that we will get their fix for
  # Ruby 2.4 "warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated"
  gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.8'
  gem 'email_spec', '~> 2.1'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8', '>= 3.8.1'
  gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 4.7', '>= 4.7.3'
  gem 'rspec-benchmark'
  gem 'listen'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'fuubar'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'rspec-json_expectations'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1'
  # I don't remember exactly the story behind this gem, just that it's related
  # to the requests omitting empty array element in json requests on tests if
  # we're not using this gem.
  gem 'rack-test', '0.6.3'
  gem 'parallel_tests', '~> 2.27'
  gem 'rspec-html-matchers', '~> 0.9.1'
  gem 'rspec-retry', '~> 0.6.1'
end

group :production do
  # full blown tagged semantic logger should run in production only
  gem 'amazing_print'
end
```

Comment: Could you add some code

Comment: what `file_watcher` do you config on your project ? `ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker` or `FileUpdateChecker`

Comment: I don't see any reference to either in my project. I'm new to rails, how can I know which one I use?

Comment: you check `file_watcher` on `config/environments/development.rb`, you could try `config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker`, iam not sure, maybe it could help.

Comment: What is your backend? Are you running this locally or deploying it to a server somewhere?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us your `Gemfile`. There are multiple gems that do hot-reload (for eg `hotreload`). Also there are diametrically opposite gems (like `spring`) which keep code in-memory to enable faster response times. Knowing which ones you are using would help us track down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Gemfile, you are using [spring gem](https://github.com/rails/spring) which is used to reload code in development while server is running. If it causing some issue, then you can restart the spring process so it will work seamlessly with new codebase. This should be required everytime you make changes in the code. I encountered this only when I am either starting with new project and a lot of code is changed. Till today, I have needed to execute this command only for 4-5 times.